# Determine if exist specified type exist in the assembly of the bin folder for the asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

All, I knew all the dll files(assembly) under the `bin` folder would be loaded when the `Asp.Net` web site start up.
But I want to know if there exist some ways to aware a specified type be defined in these assembly. thanks.

**Added**
I have a website. and I also defined a interface in an individual dll like below.

```
public class ICustomizeComponent
{
   string someMethod();
}
```

And I want to other people can reference it , and implement it and  deploy the dll to the website.

In the website .If a implement class of interface was found in the website .I will initialize the class and call the `someMethod` at given time (for example in the Page Load).The problem is I can't know what the exact name of the dll. because it is named by others who want to implement the interface.

The code which call the method looks like below.

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
   protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            //Determine if exist the implemented class, then call the `SomeMethod`
            .....  

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

}
```

All the web page in the web site would inheriti from `BasePage`.

Actually. What I trying to do is provide a way to make other people add their customization into the website.
I hope I made the problem clear . If not.  Any Comments are appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Please try to explain what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @CodeCaster updated , please review it .thanks.